# How to import * with __import__

Tags: python, import

What's the best approach to execute the following using `__import__` so that I may dynamically specify the module?

```
from module import *
```

Comment: But you are aware that you should avoid using `import *` ?

Comment: Not here for a semantics lecture :)

Comment: You want it in the locals? You shouldn't try to do this, but Michael Mrozek's answer is completely wrong anyways. Ignacio's answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the same as a normal from-import call, you just pass it a list containing `'*'` for the `fromlist`:

```
moduleName = "foo"
__import__(moduleName, globals(), locals(), ['*'])
```

Comment: That doesn't actually setup locals() though, which is the issue I'm having :)

Comment: According to the doc the standard `__import__` doesn't even use the `locals` argument. If you override `__builtin__.__import__` you can see exactly what happens when you run `from foo import *`, it seems to do exactly that

Comment: It doesnt actual import the attributes, which is the problem. It loads them into memory but it doesn't set them under the current modules locals().

Comment: I was completely ignoring the globals(), locals() arguments here. Makes sense now (a year later :)

Answer (score 17):

The only way I found:

```
module = __import__(module, globals(), locals(), ['*'])
for k in dir(module):
    locals()[k] = getattr(module, k)
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? I smell bad code. || On the other hand, feel free to accept your own answers.

Comment: This seems like the best option for getting things done quickly. The other option I've found is to do: "cmd = 'from %s import *' % moduleName; exec(cmd)". Everyone will scream but for tiny scripts it seems like the best way.

Comment: [The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#locals)

Answer (score 5):

`__import__()` never adds anything to the local scope. You will have to go through the returned module, accessing its attributes as desired.