# Adding a model with a variable name in the main model

Tags: django, django-models

I have several files with names like: mod1.py, mod2.py, mod3.py, etc.
They consist of unique Models and Fields.

mod1.py:

```
from django.db import models
class Report(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    ...
```

models.py:

```
import random.random
id_part = random(1,10)
__import__('apps.reports.mod%s' % id_part)
```

When I try `import` it, the class is not found.

```
from models import Report
```

Is it possible to add another model in the model file with a variable name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your models aren't imported in the scope of `models.py` So you need to somehow implement `from foo import *` dynamically. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916374/how-to-import-with-import) you can find a solution (not very elegant).

Anyway it's very strange approach.